# {NodeJS} "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client NodeJS"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rest, web

What I did wrong here?
I receive "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client NodeJS", can somebody help me?

I am using:

Express
mongoose (for MongoDB)

**Controller**

```
export const postResetPasswordEmail: Controller = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
   const { email } = req.body
   try {
      const errors: IValidatorError = getValidationErrors(req)
      if (Object.keys(errors).length !== 0) {
         res.status(403).json({ errors })
         return
      }
      const user = await User.findOne({ email })
      if (!user) {
         res.status(404).json({ message: AuthenticationErrors.noEmailFound })
         return
      } else {
         if (!(user.passwordUpdatedAt === undefined || (new Date(user.passwordUpdatedAt) < new Date()))) {
            res.status(404).json({ message: AuthenticationErrors.error10MinutesPassword })
            return
         }
      }
      const token = generateJWT({ email }, JWTKEY, '10m')
      await sendResetPasswordMail(email, token, next)
      res.status(200)
         .json({ message: SuccessMessages.resetPassword })
   } catch (err: any) {
      catchError(err, next)
   }
}
```

***sendResetPasswordMail***

```
const sendResetPasswordMail: SendResetPasswordMail = async (userEmail: string, token: string, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
   try {
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
         service: 'gmail',
         auth: {
            user: adminEmail.email,
            pass: adminEmail.pass
         }
      })
      const mailOptions = {
         from: adminEmail.email,
         to: userEmail,
         subject: 'Reset password',
         text: `Reset password: http://localhost:3000/resetPassword?token=${token}`
      }
      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
   } catch (err: any) {
      catchError(err, next)
   }
}
```

***generateJWT***

```
const generateJWT: GenerateJWT = (userInfo: IUserInfo, JWTKEY: string, expireTime: string): string =>
   jwt.sign({ ...userInfo }, JWTKEY, { expiresIn: expireTime })
```

Comment: May you show me how?

Comment: Which exact request gets that error?  Please show all the code from the very beginning of the request to the end so we can follow the entire path of the request being handled.

Comment: What does `catchError()` do?

Comment: I receive this error from controller. At the end of else. (line)

Comment: ```const catchError: CatchError = (error: any, next: NextFunction): void => {
   !error.statusCode ? error.statusCode = 500 : null
   next(error)
}```

Comment: put some console.log on each case to catch if twice enter their case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a flaw in **sendResetPasswordMail**:
Suppose you have an exception there and it calls **catchError** within **sendResetPasswordMail** catch block, in this case it will indirectly call **next**, which in turn would call res.status().send() within default express error handler.

Nevertheless, despite the exception **sendResetPasswordMail** will return control to you controller which would try to send status 200 after that, and if by that time the error handler's already sent the response you will get the error.

The valid behaviour would be not to catch exceptions within **sendResetPasswordMail** and leave it to the caller. And you also can remove **next** parameter from **sendResetPasswordMail**